# Placeholder not working inside a mat-form-field Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, placeholder

The placeholder for input which is "Search Here" is not working.
is it because its inside a mat-form-field ?

the Css file for input class is only

```
.search-input{
    width:100%;
    
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

```
<mat-form-field   class="search"  floatLabel="never" >
        <mat-label for="search"></mat-label>
          <input class="search-input" matInput value=""  id="search" placeholder="Search here" name="search" type="text" (change)="inputChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchText" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (input)="onChange()">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
            <mat-option [hidden]="!showPeople"  (click)="submitSearch()" [value]="getFullName(user)" *ngFor="let user of persons"><mat-icon class="option">person</mat-icon>{{getFullName(user)}}</mat-option>
            <mat-option  [hidden]="!showEvents" (click)="submitSearch()" [value]="event.eventName"*ngFor="let event of events "><mat-icon class="option">event</mat-icon>{{event.eventName}}</mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
          <button type="button" (click)="submitSearch()" mat-icon-button matSuffix class="search-button"><mat-icon><span style="font-weight: bolder;">search</span></mat-icon></button>
      </mat-form-field>
```

I tried different things but none actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I used an example from the documentation and it works, [check my example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xhdqp?file=src/app/autocomplete-filter-example.html)

```
 <form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="search" floatLabel="auto">
    <input
      class="search-input"
      matInput
      placeholder="Search here"
      aria-label="Search here"
      type="text"
      [formControl]="myControl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option
        *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
        [value]="option"
      >
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```